# Best YouTube gem for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, youtube, rubygems

Is there a definitive gem for the YouTube API? I'm trying to use youtube_g, but it seems to break on some basic stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a list of alternative github clients. maybe they do a better job:

- http://github.com/dennmart/youtube_rest/tree/master
- http://github.com/edgarjs/youtube-model/tree/master
- http://github.com/mikedamage/ruby_tube/tree/master

source: http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=33219

Answer (score 15):

I had started patching youtube_g to get it working for my needs, and then I got contacted by kylejginavan who was working on consolidating all the forks into a single maintained version, which is available now at https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it.  Last update was November 28.

Answer (score 9):

https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it or youtube_it is the new version of youtube_g.  This was forked and enhanced.  If you need any enhancement please reach out to me.  I hope keep youtube_it as the best ruby youtube gem.

Comment: @kylejginavan Hey nice to see to awesome work. Its really awesome with such a good description. I want to search movies using youtube.com/movies.. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 2):

I love youtube_it (https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it) - I first checked its github commits to see if its active and started using it. I don't use much of its features, but searching for videos work flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/grosser/youtube_search

Dead-simple / no dependencies / no api-key required

Answer (score 1):

there's a fully-functional youtube gem being worked on

latest release: http://shanesbrain.net/2007/6/12/youtube-gem-0-8-6-released

Comment: It's highly humorous to see 'being worked on' and a URL from 2007 cited as the latest release.

Answer (score 0):

you can see a demo of the youtube_it gem here

http://youtube-it.heroku.com/

the code is available too, enjoy the best gem for youtube!