# youtube api for rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, youtube-api

Is there a wrapper on youtube api for ruby on rails 3 ?

```
I have created one application in rails 3. I want to use youtube api any have a api then suggest me
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582773/best-youtube-gem-for-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=33219

Answer (score 1):

use the gem 'youtube_it'.  Then in a controller or helper...

```
  client = YouTubeIt::Client.new(:dev_key => "dev_key_supplied_by_youtube_after_you_register_for_their_api")
  videos = client.videos_by(:user => "some persons youtube username)
  count = videos.total_result_count
```

Then in view

```
  <%= "So and so has <%= count %> videos on youtube" %>
```