# search for and embed youtube videos in ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube, youtube-api

I have a website where I want to basically allow people to display several youtube videos onto the same page.

For example, I have a friend who has 3 different videos. Instead of sending a link to the three videos individually, they would go to my site see the 3 search boxes, search for the videos individually (the search is done on youtube), then they can pick the videos and click "done", at which point, the 3 videos would be embedded on their page.

I'm trying to figure out how to approach this in ruby on rails, but I'm not finding much information on how.

Here's a link from 2009 of a guy who's saying that he can actually do the search and retrieve from youtube: http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=30443

But I don't know how to do the search & retrieve, and I don't know how to do the embed. I think I can figure out the embed, but what's the best way to do the search/display results?

Thanks a lot for your help stackoverflow, you're my only hope (besides google, but google failed me today).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need to know about the search feature is described in [YouTube Data Api](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters.html). You will need your app to communicate with this API. The best thing to do may be to look after a gem specialized in this ; [there is a list available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582773/best-youtube-gem-for-ruby) in another StackOverflow question.